# PHP - Unique hashing function thats only 4 digits (doesnt need to be exact)

Tags: php, hash, url-shortener

I'm building a simple URL shortening script, I want to hash the URL to serve as a unique id but if I used something like MD5 the URL wouldn't be very short.

Is their some hashing functions or anyway to create a unique ID thats only 4 or 5 digits long?

Comment: nothing of 4-5 digits will be unique.

Comment: a general form of my comment above. Any string of length `n` with dictionary-size `x` will never have combinations more than `n * x`, which is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use auto incrementing integers and convert them into identifiers consisting of all letters (lower & uppercase) to shorten them:

```
function ShortURL($integer, $chr='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {    
// the $chr has all the characters you want to use in the url's;    
    $base = strlen($chr);
// number of characters = base
    $string = '';
    do {
        // start looping through the integer and getting the remainders using the base
        $remainder = $integer % $base;      
        // replace that remainder with the corresponding the $chr using the index
        $string .= $chr[$remainder];
        // reduce the integer with the remainder and divide the sum with the base
        $integer = ($integer - $remainder) / $base;
    } while($integer > 0);

       // continue doing that until integer reaches 0;
    return $string;

}
```

and the corresponding function to get them back to integers:

```
function LongURL($string, $chr='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
       // this is just reversing everything that was done in the other function, one important thing to note is to use the same $chr as you did in the ShortURL
        $array = array_flip(str_split($chr));

        $base = strlen($chr);
        $integer = 0;
        $length = strlen($string);


        for($c = 0; $c < $length; ++$c) {
            $integer += $array[$string[$c]] * pow($base, $length - $c - 1);
        }
        return $integer;


    }
```

Comment: This looks interesting but I have no idea how it works...could you add comments so I can use the code but also learn from it?

Comment: but this is not always generating a string of length 4 or 5, for example using short numbers like 1,2,3 ...

Answer (score 3):

Hashing will cause collisions. Just use an autoincrementing value. This includes using alphanumeric characters too to compress it. That is how most URL shortners work.

niklas's answer below is wonderfully done.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: An incrementing 4 digit value will limit you to 9999, I would work in base 36 (0-9, a-z) if you plan to do this which will give you 1,679,616 possible values.

Comment: hence my edit w/ alpha numeric. Also it would be 10k not 9999.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using MD5 (or equivalent methods) is that the number of possibilities is so large that you can, for all practical purposes, assume that the value is unique.  To ensure that a 4-digit random-like ID is unique would require a database to track existing IDs.

Essentially you have to repeatedly generate IDs and check against the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just keep the first 5 characters of a MD5 and if it already exists you add a random value to the url-string and retry until you get a unique one.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the code and ran it, and it appears that he string function are backwards.  I entered the number generated in the shorturl and ran it back thought and got a different number.  So I decoded the number and found the string has to be fed back into long url in reverse with the current coding above.